# Implementing TPCircularBuffer in C++ Class

Tags: c++, signal-processing, audiokit, the-amazing-audio-engine

I am trying to implement a circular buffer in my class.

If I initiate it in the init method, it works, but I wanna declare the buffer variable under private, so I can access it from anywhere inside the class:

```
#import "AudioKit/TPCircularBuffer.h"

class MyClass{
public:
MyClass() { //.. 
}

MyClass(int id, int _channels, double _sampleRate)
{
   // if I uncomment the following line, it works:
   // TPCircularBuffer cbuffer;
   TPCircularBufferInit(&cbuffer, 2048);
}
private:
   // this doesn't work:
   TPCircularBuffer cbuffer;
};
```

Doing this leads to the following compiling error:
*Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'MyClass'*

I don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

Since [`TPCircularBuffer`](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Utilities/Circular%20Buffer/TPCircularBuffer.h#L64) has a `volatile` data member, it is trivially non-copiable. This makes your class trivially non-copiable.

If you need copy semantics on `MyClass`, you need to provide your own copy constructor:

```
MyClass(MyClass const& other) : // ...
{
    TPCircularBufferInit(&cbuffer, 2048); // doesn't copy anything, but you might want to
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I still need some time to process that information and get a grasp of what it all means..